# How to deal with Form Collection on Symfony2 Beta?

Tags: forms, collections, symfony, one-to-many

I have an entity User and an entity Address. There is a relation One-to-Many between User and Address :

```
    class User
    {
        /**
        * @orm:OneToMany(targetEntity="Address")
        */
        protected $adresses;

        [...]

    }
```

I have a class AddressType, and class UserType :

```
    class UserType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder->add('addresses', 'collection', array('type' => new AddressType()));

        }

        [...]
    }
```

In my controller, I build form with :

```
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new UserType());
```

... and create view with :

```
    return array('form' => $form->createView());
```

I display form field in my twig template with :

```
    {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
    {{ form_label(form.name) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
    [...]
```

Okay. Now, how to display fields for one or more addresses ? (it's no `{{ for_widget(form.adresses.zipcode) }}` nor `{{ for_widget(form.adresses[0].zipcode) }}` ...)

Any ideas ?

Comment: Your spelling is very inconsistent across your example code; are you being sure to spell things (variable names, functions, etc) correctly in your development environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I did it in my form template:

```
{{ form_errors(form.addresses) }}

{% for address in form.addresses %}
    <div id="{{ 'address%sDivId'|format(loop.index) }}" class="userAddressItem">
        <h5> Address #{{ loop.index }}</h5>

        {{ form_errors(address) }}
        {{ form_widget(address) }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

And I have a small action bar, driven by jQuery, that lets the user add and remove addresses. It is a simple script appending a new div to the container with the right HTML code. For the HTML, I just used the same output has Symfony but with updated index. For example, this would be the output for the street input text of the `AddressType` form:

`<input id="user_addresses_0_street" name="user[addresses][0][street]" ...>`

Then, the next index Symfony will accept is 1 so the new input field you add would look like this:

`<input id="user_addresses_1_street" name="user[addresses][1][street]" ...>`

Note: The three dots are a remplacement for `required="required" maxlength="255"` but could change depending on your needs.

You will need more HTML code than that to add a whole new `AddressType` to the DOM of the browser but this give you the general idea.

Regards, 
Matt

Comment: Thanks! It helped me to debug my code. Symfony2 generates successfully fields, including a pattern (has index `$$name$$`). it must be hidden and used to make empty group fields displayed to user, with the index 0, 1, 2 ...

Comment: Good and thanks also for the tip about the pattern. I didn't think about using the prototype as a pattern for an easy seachr & replace for new fields. This is a great idea and it will reduce my js code. Thumbs up!

Comment: Just FYI, it's "address" not "adress"

Comment: Oups thanks, I'm used to write it in french which is spelled `adresse`. I edited my answer to fix this typo.

Answer (score 5):

I should top that up with the fact that if you want to dynamically add fields, you need to set the key 'allow_add' to true in your collection field in UserType :

```
...

$builder->add('addresses', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new AddressType(),
    'allow_add' => true
));
```

Just spent hours trying to figure out what was missing, and at the time i'm writing the doc does not mention this yet. Hope it'll help fellow developers.